# enum data types in switch statement c++

Tags: c++, enums, switch-statement

First bear with me,I am a noob.

I was trying to write a program that outputs days of the week. Say for example if one enters day1 it outputs Sunday, day2 Monday and so on. I used a switch statement with an int mapped onto an enum for the switch cases. The problem I seem to be having is that it does no seem to work, at least not when I input day1. It works as expected when I use int values 1 through 7. I have tried to find solutions to this and so far am only hitting walls kindly help.

Here's my code:

```
enum days{day1,day2,day3,day4,day5,day6,day7};
int day;

cout<<"Enter the day of the week in format day1 through day7 ";
cin>>day;

   switch(day)
   {
    case day1:
    cout<<"Sunday";
    break;

    case day2 :
    cout<<"Monday";
    break;`
   }
```

Comment: It starts with 0 by default, not 1.

Comment: `std::cin` doesn't automatically translate string input to the enum defined numbers.

Comment: After `cin>>day;`, add one line: `cout<<day;`. Then you'll see what you're doing to your string inputs.

Comment: Enum values don't have string representation. Characters `'d','a','y','1'` in an IO stream are not in any way connected with the enumeration constant `day1`. If you want a connection you must program one yourself.

Comment: cin>> day will accept an int only. Value entered can be from 1 to 7 and not day1 to day7. And you need to add in enum declaration as day1=1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take input like `day1`, `day2` etc, then why did you declared the input variable as `int`, it should be `char` array..
If you want to take input like `1`, `2` then it's kinda okk...

If you want to input string and then compare it with enum values then first you have to convert it into an integer value.

you can do this,

```
char day[4];
cin>>day;
int d=day[3]-49;
```

then use it in the switch as you did..

```
switch(d)
{
case days::day1:
cout<<"Sunday";
break;

case days::day2 :
cout<<"Monday";
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your users to enter day1 and to map it to your enum, you need to parse integer value from input yourself. You can either read it as string and then do parsing yourself or use slightly non C++ solution with scanf:

```
int dayNum = 0;
char buff[16];
scanf("%[^0-9]%d", buff, &dayNum);
```

also remember that enums start from value 0, if you want them to start from 1 then you must change enum to:

```
enum days{day1=1,day2,day3,day4,day5,day6,day7};
              ^^
```

day2, day3 etc. will have values 2,3,...